# Creating json from string captured with text.match

Tags: javascript, html

Dynamic creation of object from string

I have the string `{"person":"me" ,"age":"30"}` embedded in a text.  I extract it from the text using

```
text.match(/{.*}/);
```

I want to be able to use the `object.keys` and `object.values` methods  to get keys to create menus dynamically and return the values based on menu selection.

It appears that I need to be able to create an object dynamically. I would like to do it without having to loop through the string. Is there any function or method that can take the result of text.match as input and give me json that can be used with `object.keys` and `object.values` etc.

Comment: Try: `var result = JSON.parse(string);`

Comment: You don't want to "create json from string." JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. In your case, you're dealing with JSON (in a string) that you want to convert to non-JSON (not a string). You do that, as the linked question's answers say, via `JSON.parse`.

Comment: Okay I want to create data that can by handled by object.keys and object.values. The structure looks like the string I have shown.

Comment: This says closed as duplicate but the proposed solution does not recognize the text.match as an object when   This is not solved